# Telegram bot is not sending messages

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to execute this simple telegram bot but I get no output and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the code:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext


def hello(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text(f'Hello {update.effective_user.first_name}')


updater = Updater('my_token')

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(hello)

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: If I run your code I do get an error: **TypeError: handler is not an instance of Handler**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed some parameters in the `add_handler` function, so it should be like the following:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', hello))
```

Comment: @Iker, Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any answers that might have helped you. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.